# using variable to filter rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe defined as below and want to filter using variable name ft as in below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=['a', 'b'])

ft=["a"]

dt=df[df[ft]==3]

print(dt)
```

I get below result:

```
a   b

NaN NaN

3.0 NaN
```

while actual result should have been only 2nd row

```
 a  b

 3  4
```

I dont want to use column name, but variable.

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use scalar `ft="a"` for `Series` `df['a']` instead one column DataFrame `df[['a']]` if `ft=["a"]`.

If need test index use:

```
ft = 3
dt = df.loc[ft]
```

If not sure if exist:

```
ft = 3
dt = df[df.index == ft]
```

For first column use:

```
ft = 3
dt = df[df.iloc[:, 0] == ft]
```

Comment: if I have to use column index in place of name or variable, how can we do that? If suppose I have to apply filter on first column value =3,  something like below: df [df[:,0]=3] am new to python. many thanks

Comment: @akumar - added to answer, I think need `dt = df[df.iloc[:, 0] == ft]`

Answer (score 0):

Or if you aren't allowed to change the `ft` variable, do:

```
>>> df[df[ft].squeeze() == 3]
   a  b
1  3  4
>>>
```